# How would I use multiple WHERE and OR in a mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return records based on the cities that someone chooses. It works fine with one city. But I tried to put the "OR" in there and it still only returns results for one city. Not both. Am I doing something wrong here. It looks okay to me but I have to be doing something wrong.

```
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT 
  lat,lng,id,re,per_num,name,city,state,zip,address,status,category,size,
  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(40.000000) ) 
               * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
               * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-75.000000) ) 
               + sin( radians(40.000000) ) 
               * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
               )
  ) AS distance 
FROM 
  buildings 
WHERE 
  (city='$cities[0]' OR city='$cities[1]') 
  AND re='$re2'
  AND status='$status2' 
  AND size='$size2' 
HAVING 
  distance < 25  
ORDER BY 
  distance 
LIMIT 
  0 , 20  
                     ");
```

Comment: Ever tried to write a *multi-line* statements?

Comment: Try `echo`-ing your query to see what is acctually being requested from server. Also, make sure that requested data exists in database... **ALSO**: Using of `HAVING` is quite unnecessary. `HAVING` is primarily used with `GROUP` and aggregate functions (`SUM`,`COUNT`, etc...)

Comment: The having is why youre getting one row

Comment: Your query looks fine, I assume one of the other parameters is stopping the results from showing up. Go back to the basics, comment every AND and just search for all buildings in the two cities. Do you get results now?

Comment: **warning** your code may be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Comment: When I remove the HAVING, it completely breaks the query

Comment: @jperovic: `HAVING` is allowed without `GROUP BY` - although it's not common.

Comment: @ypercube: Yes, that's why I said "primarily" :)

Comment: @jperovic: Yeah, the OP is using the "feature" of MySQL to refer to aliases (set in SELECT list) in the `HAVING` clause. In ANSI SQL, this would not be allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is constrained not only by your $cities entries but also by

```
AND re='$re2' AND status='$status2' AND size='$size2'
```

And also by

```
 HAVING distance < 25
```

May the missing city entrie not comply to any of those constraints, it won't be in the request result.

Comment: Thats what I thought at first but I check the database and there are records that exist for that particular query but still it only returns one city

Comment: are you sure of the content of your $cities php array (whitespaces or unattended empty values) may come in the way.

Comment: @Nic: You can also try removing the `LIMIT 0,20` part. Perhaps this is the cause.

Comment: You can also test by putting just the 2nd city in the query: `WHERE city='$cities[1]' AND ...` If it returns results, then the `LIMIT` is the cause. You have more than 20 results from the first city, so nothing is shown from the second.